# I created two CORES in solr for different data how i can access core dynamically using java cade

Tags: java, apache, solr, lucene, solrj

I created two CORES in solr for different data ,how i can access core dynamically using java cade.

Thanks,
In advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to use different url

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/core1/select?q=*:*
http://localhost:8983/solr/core2/select?q=*:*
```

solr config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<solr> 
    <cores adminPath="/admin/cores">
        <core name="core1" instanceDir="core1" />
        <core name="core2" instanceDir="core2" />
    </cores>

    <queryResultWindowSize>100</queryResultWindowSize>
</solr>
```

core config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config>
  <luceneMatchVersion>LUCENE_43</luceneMatchVersion>
  <requestDispatcher handleSelect="false">
    <httpCaching never304="true" />
  </requestDispatcher>
  <requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler" />
  <requestHandler name="/update" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler" />
  <requestHandler name="/admin" class="solr.admin.AdminHandlers" />
  <requestHandler name="/analysis/field" class="solr.FieldAnalysisRequestHandler" startup="lazy" />
</config>
```

Comment: my solr.xml file is like                                       <solr persistent="true" sharedLib="lib"> <cores adminPath="/admin/cores" host="${host:}" defaultCoreName="accountentitlements" hostPort="${jetty.port:8983}" hostContext="${hostContext:solr}">
    <core name="core0" instanceDir="core0" />
    <core name="core1" instanceDir="core1" />
  <core name="accountentitlements" instanceDir="accountentitlements" />
  </cores>
</solr>  but when i running my code it takes Collection1 Bydefault core.Please tell me descriptive because i am new in solr.